# File does not upload to server using the library Volley( android/php)

Tags: php, android, android-volley

Tell me,i sent to the server text + file. File - photos. Necessary permissions are registered in the manifest.

** The text of the server receives ** but the server does not receive a file. Please, help me to send file and text.
The Code php web pages good working, i test from a browser and text + file a received

**UPDATE:
I took into account all the comments and modified code, photo still does not get to the server**
When i pick photo in gallery i see my tag in log

```
11-15 15:24:45.583 7942-7942/com.handlingcitizen.handlingcitizen E/GetpathImageGalery: Cool/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20161113090426.jpg
```

Key:

```
   public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "fileFF";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "nameFF";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "contactFF";
public static final String KEY_NASELPUNKT = "gorodFF";
public static final String KEY_DOM = "homeFF";
public static final String KEY_STREET = "streetFF";
public static final String KEY_MESAGES = "messageFF";
```

Upload file:

```
 private void openGalery() {
    if (checker.lacksPermissions(PERMISSIONS_READ_STORAGE)) {
        startPermissionsActivity(PERMISSIONS_READ_STORAGE);
    } else {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
}

private void opnenCamera() {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("Getpath", "Cool" + mCurrentPhotoPath);
    return image;
}


public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && data != null && requestCode == 1) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            int targetWi = imageViewUppload.getWidth();
            int targetHi = imageViewUppload.getHeight();
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptionsgalery = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);

            //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
            filename = filePath.getLastPathSegment();


            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptionsgalery);
            int photoW = bmOptionsgalery.outWidth;
            int photoH = bmOptionsgalery.outHeight;
            int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetWi, photoH / targetHi);

            // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
            bmOptionsgalery.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptionsgalery.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
            bmOptionsgalery.inPurgeable = true;

            Bitmap bitmaptoimge = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getPath(filePath), bmOptionsgalery);
            Log.e("GetpathImageGalery", "Cool" + getPath(filePath));
            imageViewUppload.setImageBitmap(bitmaptoimge);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Фото сохранено и выбрано!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = imageViewUppload.getWidth();
        int targetH = imageViewUppload.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        imageViewUppload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        showError("Вы не выбрали файл");
    }


}



private void bottomnavigation(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottomnavigationview, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {
            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.action_1:
                    opnenCamera();

                    break;
                case R.id.action_2:
                    openGalery();
                    break;

            }
        }
    });
}

public void showError(String errorMessage) {
    Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



public void uploadImage() {
    if (checker.lacksPermissions(PERMISSIONS_INTERNET)) {
        startPermissionsActivity(PERMISSIONS_INTERNET);
    } else {

        //Showing the progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading =
                ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        //Disimissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Showing toast message of the response
                        String otvet = null;
                        try {
                            otvet = URLDecoder
                                    .decode(URLEncoder.encode(s, "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, otvet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                //Dismissing the progress dialog
                loading.dismiss();

                //Showing toast
                String error = volleyError.toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (volleyError.networkResponse == null) {
                    if (volleyError.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                        // Show timeout error message
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oops. Timeout error!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            }
        }) {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                //Getting Image Name
                name = nameFF.getText().toString().trim();
                //озвращает строку с вырезанными пробельными символами

                naselpunkt = naspunkt.getText().toString().trim();

                street = ulica.getText().toString().trim();

                house = dom.getText().toString().trim();

                e_mail = email.getText().toString().trim();

                message = mesages.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating parameters
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                //Adding parameters

                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, getPath(filePath));
                params.put(KEY_NAME, name);
                params.put(KEY_NASELPUNKT, naselpunkt);
                params.put(KEY_STREET, street);
                params.put(KEY_DOM, house);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL, e_mail);
                params.put(KEY_MESAGES, message);

                //returning parameters
                return params;

            }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

PHP code:

```
 <?php
if (isset ($_POST['contactFF'])) {
  $to = "ukpmo"; // поменять на свой электронный адрес
  $from = $_POST['contactFF'];
  $subject = "Заполнена контактная форма с ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $message = "Фамилия, собственное имя, отчество (если таковое имеется) либо инициалы гражданина: \n".$_POST['nameFF'].
  "\nНаселенный пункт: ".$_POST['gorodFF'].
  "\nУлица: ".$_POST['streetFF'].
  "\nдом, квартира/офис: ".$_POST['homeFF'].
  "\nEmail: ".$from.
  "\nДата отправки сообщения: ".$date_today = date("d.m.Y H:i").
  "\nИзложение сути обращения: ".$_POST['messageFF'];

  $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
  $filesize = '';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
  $message="
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message";
  for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['fileFF']['name']);$i++) {
     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
         $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])));
         $filename = $_FILES['fileFF']['name'][$i];
         $filetype = $_FILES['fileFF']['type'][$i];
         $filesize += $_FILES['fileFF']['size'][$i];
         $message.="

--$boundary
Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

$attachment";
     }
   }
   $message.="
--$boundary--";

  if ($filesize < 10000000) { // проверка на общий размер всех файлов. Многие почтовые сервисы не принимают вложения больше 10 МБ
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $_POST['nameFF'].', Ваше сообщение получено, спасибо!';
  } else {
    echo 'Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 10 МБ.';
  }
}
?>
```

File upload code and text through a browser:

```
    Request URL:http://dfg.by/wp-content/themes/reverie-master/contacts.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:148.114.138.185:80
Response Headers
view parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Nov 2016 17:39:00 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Request Headers
view parsed
POST /wp-content/themes/reverie-master/contacts.php HTTP/1.1
Host: ukp.mogilev.by
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 47014
Origin: http://ukp.mogilev.by
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLgacUgprclABmklr
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://ukp.mogilev.by/elektronnye-obrashcheniya-grazhdan/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: _ym_uid=1478194399500303049; _ym_isad=1; _ym_visorc_28369546=w
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryLgacUgprclABmklr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nameFF"

тест
------WebKitFormBoundaryLgacUgprclABmklr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gorodFF"

тест
------WebKitFormBoundaryLgacUgprclABmklr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="streetFF"

тест
------WebKitFormBoundaryLgacUgprclABmklr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="streetFF"

тест
------WebKitFormBoundaryLgacUgprclABmklr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="streetFF"

q@tut.by
------WebKitFormBoundaryLgacUgprclABmklr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messageFF"

тест
------WebKitFormBoundaryLgacUgprclABmklr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileFF[]"; filename="3.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryLgacUgprclABmklr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileFF[]"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryLgacUgprclABmklr--
```

Answer (score 1):

```
params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
```

is the same as

```
params.put("fileFF", image);
```

which in your case is

```
params.put("fileFF", a base64 encoded string containing an image);
```

So you are not sending a file in the usual way but only a POST parameter.

In your php schript you can get the contens of the file with:

```
$image = base64_decode($_POST['fileFF']);
```

Comment: please tell me what I need to change?

Comment: how I must correct  send the file?
server is not mine, I can not change anything there

Comment: Then please google for examples how to post a file with Volley. You do not have to change much in your code. And do NOT base64 encode the file! Just use a `File` instance to indicate the file to be uploaded.

Comment: @ greenapps

I looked at Google but is there any reference to sending only a photo but not the file ... please help, I do not understand how to properly

Comment: `sending only a photo but not the file .` ??? Well i do not properly understand that.

Comment: `params.put(KEY_IMAGE, getPath(filePath));` That will not include the contents of that file. That will only send the path to the file. I wonder why you cannot find a Volley example how to post a file. Pretty basic stuff i would think.